# Using Abstract class as type in spring database

Tags: spring, kotlin

So I have a class which I'm trying to store database, moreover there are mapper built for Spec class to store in database.

```
data class Spec(
 payload: SpecPayload?
 type: SpecType
)

abstract class SpecPayload {
...
}

data class LinkPayload(
) : SpecPayload()

data class CodePayload(
): SpecPayload()
```

But I'm getting this error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `SpecPayload` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questions, the reason it failed cause I wasn't using `@Component` over class.